# Why are there multiple Servers in my PgAdmin?

Tags: pgadmin, postgresql-9.3

I recently installed `PgAdmin 1.18.1` on my computer, with a pretty standard installation.

When I open it, I see a list of three servers, and when I create a database in one, it creates a database in all the others.

Why is this happening? What's the deal with all these servers?

[image: PGAdmin Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important thing is that they are 3 different connections to the same server, that's why when you make a change in one of them it propagates to the other ones.

Each one of those "servers" actually represents a connection to a database. You will add extra "server" for each different user connecting to the same database for example.

The last one, x86 probably uses a 64bit library while the second one uses a 32bit library (Because you have a 64bit OS, the second one works for backwards compatibility). 
The first one appears to work with a different background behaviour, as a way to offer a special Postgres feature, spatial database management (http://postgis.net/). It probably offers extra options when creating tables/columns

Comment: So each time I add a user, I will see another "connection to a database"?

Comment: If you just add the user you won't, but if you want to open a connection to the database with that user, you will create a new server with the same url, database name and the new user and it's password, and this new connection will appear in the list.